# What will happen if I paginate over s3 bucket files and put new files concurrently

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I have lots of files in a "source" S3 bucket and I want to copy them to "dest" bucket. But at the same time new files are put into the "source" bucket. The question is, will the paginator see new uploaded files? And if not how could I track them for paginating again is costly?

My code (using aws-sdk-go-v2):

```golang
paginator := s3.NewListObjectsV2Paginator(client, &s3.ListObjectsV2Input{
    Bucket: bucket,
})

for paginator.HasMorePages() {
    page, err := paginator.NextPage(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Errorf("error: %+v", err)
        return
    }
    for _, obj := range page.Contents {
        // copy object
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj What exactly? This code iterates over files in my "source" bucket, it works. The question is can it see newly uploaded files while iterating

Comment: Ok but you can run a test by yourself. Just iterate and create a new file in the bucket.

Comment: I don’t know specifics about s3 but gcs works with a query system that I can pass the last file and it can continue from it. This way I don’t need to loop over and over until find a new entry

Comment: However you must check the documentation of this paginator in particular. Maybe it hide this complexity via an elegant api

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj Oh, I see your confusion. This code works as you described, it starts from the last returned file, but the thing is that s3 returns files in lexicographical order, and that’s the problem. I have no guarantee that new uploaded file will be placed after the last returned. Unfortunately, I couldn’t find any mention of this in the documentation, so I came here

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you should definitely test your code but...

it's worth mentioning that since December 2020 S3 is **Strong Read-After-Write Consistency**.

In other words,

> all S3 GET, PUT, and [LIST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html#API_ListObjectsV2_RequestSyntax) operations, as well as operations that change object tags, ACLs, or metadata, are now strongly consistent. What you write is what you will read, and the results of a LIST will be an accurate reflection of what’s in the bucket. This applies to all existing and new S3 objects, works in all regions [...]

More on that in [this blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-update-strong-read-after-write-consistency/).

And according to the AWS GO SDK

> Pagination methods iterate over a list operation until the method retrieves the last page of results or until the callback function returns false

Comment: "results of a LIST will be an accurate reflection of what’s in the bucket" but at what point in time?  I don't conclude from that quote that a LIST at time X will include any objects created thereafter, but it doesn't clearly say it doesn't either.  My hunch would be that objects created after the LIST was called would *not* be in the LIST.  But I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply reading the files and writing them to a second bucket, but otherwise leaving them the same content, S3 can do this for you with [bucket replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-how-setup.html).

If you need to do some processing beyond what S3's built-in replication can do, the best way is with event bridge, which will automatically handle incoming objects.  For resiliency, I recommend connecting the event bridge to SQS and the SQS to a lambda function.  You can then run an idempotent version of your syncing program to pick up any objects that came in before the event bridge was set up.  Find some way to know whether the object was replicated or not (object tags might help here), and you can run it until all objects are synced.

Either way, new objects will be synced in the future.